# How can I direct awstats to count exe and dmg files as downloads?

Tags: awstats

Awstats apparently counts .exe and .dmg files as page views, instead of as downloads. I would like it to count them as downloads instead. How can I achieve that? How does Awstats determine whether something is a page view or a download?

I know about the extra section support, but I don't want a separate section, as I have downloads of many different types on my site, most of which are correctly listed as downloads. I would just like for .exe and .dmg files to appear there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself by reading the code. It turns out that this information is in the `mime.pm` reference file which awstats reads at startup. On my Ubuntu system this file is in `/usr/share/awstats/lib`. It contains lines like this:

```py
'ini',['conf',''],
'dtd',['dtd',''],
# Program
'exe',['runtime',''],
'jnlp',['jnlp',''],
```

It maps extensions to a family and a file type, which can be empty or `p` for a page, `i` for an image or `d` for a download. It's easy to change the file type here, and to add missing extensions. I just changed the `''` next to `'exe'` to `'d'`, and added a line for the `dmg` type.

You'll have to reprocess your log files if you want to fix your existing statistics.